# How can I get an image and text to appear next to each other in a title bar

Tags: blackberry, screen

I'm building a screen in a blackberry application and I'd like an icon/image to be to the left of it's title text.
Is there a way that this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a [MainScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html), you should be able to add a [HorizontalFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/HorizontalFieldManager.html) as the title field.   Then you just add the image and text to the HorizontalFieldManager.